# Why are there 4 columns, not 5 in the iris dataset?

Tags: scikit-learn

I just started machine learning a few days ago, and I saw that when I want the shape(in sklearn), it is displaying the shape as 150 observations and 4 features, but for those who know, the iris dataset has 5 columns, namely the petal length, petal width, sepal length and, sepal width, and species.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
iris.data.shape

>>>(150,4)
```

As you can see, there are 150 rows and 4 columns.

Why is this so?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check iris.target for the class label.
iris.data will have only features and iris.target will have the class label (species)